# Using Nan to write a node.js addon, how can I return an object with a few properties?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I'm new to node, and newer to Nan, but I need to write an addon that wraps some existing C code to return values to Javascript. I have defined the classes, and am able to return basic types, but I need to return a custom class from C++ to Javascript. I have a class:

```
class SomeClass : public Nan::ObjectWrap
{
 public: 
  ScanStatus();
  static void Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports);
  int start;
  int end;
  int current;
  int found;
private:
  ~ScanStatus();
  static void New(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &info);
  static void GetStart(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &info);
  static void GetEnd(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &info);
  static void GetCurrent(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &info);
  static void GetFound(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &info);
  static Nan::Persistent<v8::Function> constructor;
}
```

I have a second class with a method that needs to return this class to Javascript. I have scoured the web, but can't find a simple example that works. 
When I try this way:

```
void OtherClass:GetSomeClass(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &info)
{
  SomeClass *sc = new SomeClass();
  sc->start = 15;
  sc->end = 16;
  sc->current = 16;
  sc->found = 2;

  info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New(sc));
}
```

The Javascript value comes back true, with no properties.